# Angular6: Form = How to choose which parameters i will send

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

In post method i need to send only parameters which is have value in form (api specifications) and not all data. Is there a way to send only touched fields

```js
{"keywords":"key, pase","fps":0,"productionYear":1920,"contentType":2,"country":"US", "tags":["trap","bad","day","anderson"],"related":[], "series": ""}
```

This is example request put method for edit movie, end i want to send only this one which is not empty string or empty array.

Here put request :

```js
return this.http
      .put(`${this.config.apiUrl}/` + requri + `/` + id, obj)
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          return this.errServ.handleError(error);
        })
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this work manually before you send an object inside request body. Consider creating a separate function to do this work.

```
//{"keywords":"key, pase","fps":0,"productionYear":1920,"contentType":2,"country":"US", "tags":["trap","bad","day","anderson"],"related":[], "series": ""}
takeNonEmptyObjects (obj) {
  const result = {}
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) return;
    const value = obj[k]
    if (value === null || value === undefined) || value === "")) {
      result[k] = obj[k];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

If you want to apply above behavior to happen for all request body, then consider calling above function from `HttpIntercepter` before making a request.

Comment: ok, so this is only way, ok i have HttpIntercepter as well i just think about it and have assumption that angular have some options but clearly have not

Comment: Yes, this is the only I can think of, otherwise you can have some middleware configured on server side before processing request.

Comment: ok, thank you, i used like this
`takeNonEmptyObjects(content: any) {
    const result = {};
    for (const key in content) {
      if (content.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const element = content[key];
        if (element !== null && element !== undefined && element !== '') {
          result[key] = content[key];
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full proof solution, which will ***identify whether your field is `Object` or a `String`, checks for values accordingly & deletes empty arrays/ nulls/ undefined's/ empty strings from the array passed*** -

```js
var data = {"keywords":"key, pase","fps":0,"productionYear":1920,"contentType":2,"country":"US", "tags":["trap","bad","day","anderson"],"related":[], "series": ""};

function cleanData(data) {
  for(let key in data) {
    if(typeof data[key] == 'string') {
      if(data[key] == null || data[key] == "" || data[key] == undefined) {
        delete data[key];
      }
    } else if(typeof data[key] == 'object') {
      if(data[key].length == 0) {
        delete data[key];
      }
    }
  }
  return data;
}

console.log(cleanData(data));
```